# Writing a CSV file to ftp

Tags: c#, csv, format, export-to-csv

I am trying to write a `.csv` file from a web service to an ftp. When I download the file after the web service has completed writing Excel reacts different in different versions of Excel. 2013 opens the file completely fine and works exactly how I want it. However 2003 has an error of the following and when I open the file all the contents are in the A column rather than spread across b,c,d etc, the comma isn't separating.

[image]

Here is the code for the c# web service

```
string delimiter = ",";

int length = filecontents.Count;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, filecontents[index]));

string fileName = name;
string ftpAddress = "myaddress";
string username = "myusername";
string password = "mypassword";

string str = sb.ToString();
byte[] buffer = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + ftpAddress + fileName);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

reqStream.Close();
```

I have tried to set `request.ContentType` to `application/CSV` and `text/CSV` both come back with errors of

> "System.NotSupportedException: This property is not supported by this
>   class. ↵   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.set_ContentType(String value)"

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated

EDIT: when using `\t` as a delimiter (tab) older versions of Excel perform how I want them to. However the newer version then don't. So I'm guessing different versions of Excel have different default delimiters, any ideas of how to force it to default to comma?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't not just `open` csv-file in Excel, but use `import` (where you can choose delimiters, etc)?

Comment: I would if it was me opening the file each time. but the file is being created for end users to then download on what ever machine they have be it top spec or something from 10+ years

Comment: Provide user with instructions, write excel vba macro for them or use another way. I have a software with primitive handmade csv-export (it doesn't even put strings into `""`, all numbers are saved in neutral culture), yet i had no problem with any of the customer, because they are instructed do not use `;` in the text and during import have to replace `.` with whatever decimal point symbol they want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've managed to sort my problem by changing:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

to

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
```

i apologize for not being able to explain this very well to any one who reads this as an answer as i dont understand it fully myself, but to me it looks as if the bytes wernt in the correct format. when looking on WinMerge (thanks to C.Evenhuis) each byte had two 0's after it so "ID" became "I00D00". well thats how it appeared in WinMerge.

Also having cell A1 as "ID" ran into problems as excel thought the file was a SYLK rather than a csv. changing it to "Id" solved this. http://sharepointonline.wordpress.com/2011/08/09/excel-has-detected-that-csv-is-a-sylk-file-but-cannot-load-it/

If any one can explain this any better please feel free to edit my answer, thought id post it anyway just incase any one else was as stuck as i was.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the [FtpWebRequest.UseBinary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.usebinary.aspx) flag to `true`, that should leave the file in tact.

Also for troubleshooting things like this, you should use some kind of file comparer (WinMerge is nice for text files) to see if the problem has anything to do with the Ftp upload. If the file already turned out to be 100% equal to what is being uploaded, remove any Ftp related information from your question as the problem then lies with how Excel treats your file.